# jQuery outerHTML close tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, outerhtml

I'm using jQuery for get outer html: `$('.page')[0].outerHTML` and this works, but I have img tags which must be closing like this: `<img src="smth" />` but outerHTML delete `/`. How solve this problem?

UPD: Well, I still have not found a solution. How get outer html without changes?

Answer (score 4):

This is not really a problem. But browser strips out the closing tag. Even if you manually use `<img src="path.jpg">` it renders correctly in the page. Though the coding practice is to use closing tags for such elements.

Have you ever noticed even if you have typed `<img src="path.jpg" />` the browser just shows the `<img src="path.jpg">` when you inspect it.

So, you don't need to be worry about this.

Comment: The fact that I use Thymeleaf (XHTML). That's why I need close img tag.

Comment: @KadzhaevMarat ...and yes you don't need to be worry even then. Because currently we all are using html5 meaning xhtml tag is used and the closing tag is stripped out by the browser..

Comment: @KadzhaevMarat You appear to be using `outerHTML` - note the *HTML* in the name - and expecting to get something that will work in XHTML. Doesn't this seem odd to you?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Ok, there is any ways to solve this problem? How I can get outer XHTML code or outerHTML but without changes?